# Restore ctrl + V for pasting in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, razor-pages

In a VS 2017 ASP.NET core razor pages project, pressing <kbd>ctrl + v</kbd> in a .cshtml file takes me to its corresponding .cs source code file. Doing the same from the .cs file brings me back to the corresponding .cshtml file.

To really paste from the clip board, i have to press <kbd>Shift + Insert</kbd>.

I'm really finding this very irritating as I have really gotten used to paste code in the IDE using <kbd>ctrl + V</kbd> over the years.

Does any one know how i can restore <kbd>ctrl + V</kbd> as paste key combination?

Comment: VS 2017 doesn't change this shortcut. Did you install a plugin that changed the keyboard shortucts? Did you check the  current shortcuts in `Environment > Keyboard` ?

Comment: Shift + Insert is mentioned even here http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Comment: From the link above, ctrl + V should work as well but it doesn't and i have no extensions installed. I have Reshaper installed but i opted to retain VS keyboard short cuts during its initial setup.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you might be right, i just reset Environment > Keyboard to Default and re-started visual studio and now CTRL + V is working.